# MDX Calculated member filter by dimension attribute and member value

Tags: filtering, ssas, mdx

I have MDX (similar to one questioned and answered here):

```
(
[PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elbas],
[Measures].[PX QUANTITY]
)
```

It works for me (it filters measures to value "Elbas" only). But I need another filtering - to have only values which are < or > than 0. There shoud be some condition similar to "[Measures].[PX QUANTITY] < 0". But I do not know how to implement it.

Thank for any of your advice.

Ondra

Table looks similar like this:

```
PX_MARKET_NAME; PX_QUANTITY

Elbas;  5

Elbas; -3

Elspot; 4
```

In result I need only 2nd value (-3). Which belongs to Elbas and is smaller then 0.

So far I tried this, but it is now working :(

```
FILTER
(
[PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elbas],
[Measures].[PX PURCHASE]
) < 0
```

Comment: If you looked at the subtotal for a geographic region (several markets) would you want the Quantity<0 check to happen at the subtotal level? Or do you want the filter to happen at the row grain of the fact table?

Comment: There will be one calculated member for values < 0 and other calculated member for values > 0.

Comment: but should it operate at the row level or the aggregated level? If a region has a +2 and a -3 should it show in the <0 calculation since the region subtotal is -1? Or do you just filter at the row level?

Comment: If there are two values (+2 and -3) I need to see as result only -3 (not -1). In case there will be three values (+2, -3, -4) the result should be -7.

Answer (score 0):

Try that:

```
IIF(
    ([PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elbas],[Measures].[PX QUANTITY]) < 0,   
    ([PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elbas],[Measures].[PX QUANTITY]),
    NULL
)
```

Comment: Can you run ([PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elbas],[Measures].[PX QUANTITY]) and calculation above to show where a gap is?

Comment: @DanyloKorostil per the comments above by the OP they want the filter to be at the row level not the aggregated level. So I think they need to create a dimension for the measure.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thanks Greg!

Comment: @DanyloKorostil or you could do this calculation in the DSV

Comment: Hi, thank you for brainstorming. I did it this way: I added another dimension (P <0; S > 0; N - everything else). Code (for < 0) now looks like this:(
 [PX Market].[PX MARKET NAME].&[Elspot],
 [BI MEC PXT].[PX TYPE].&[P],
 [Measures].[PX Market Trade Quantity]
)